# AR9462 working only from command line and only with WEP

Tags: wireless, lenovo

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on this machine
http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/tablets/lenovo/miix-series/miix-2-11-inch/

It has several issues that I didn't solved yet, but the most annoying thing is that it has problems with network connection. This computer does not have any ethernet, so only way how to connect is via WiFi.

```
lspci

02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

I am able to connect to my AP only via WEP encryption through these commands

```
iwconfig wlan0 enc on
iwconfig wlan0 ap any essid AP_ESSID_NAME key s:WEP_ASCII_PASSWORD
ifconfig wlan0 up
dhclient wlan0
```

From the desktop environment it is not possible. Even if I am connected from command line the "Indicator Applet Complete" is still showing network disconnected and "Enable WiFi" or "WiFi Networks" are still disabled.

Connecting to WPA network through command line is not so easy so I didn't tested it yet. I found there some issues with WPA and this chipset, but I think my problem is something else.

Any suggestions how to manage WiFi in user friendly way from GUI, or where to search what is wrong? 
I want to use this device as tablet and not wear the keyboard all the time, and anyway typing on its tiny keyboard is possible, but not comfortable.

Answer (score 0):

I've been dealing with this issue on the same system (Lenovo Miix 2 11), and it seems to happen on any distribution. Manual configuration works, but apparently Network-Manager (and others) respect the "rfkill" switch. I haven't looked into the airplane key much (still trying to get some version of Linux installed), but I do have a work around:

```
sudo rmmod ideapad-laptop
```

It seems like some Yoga models have problems with this module too, so you can look in various forums for "rfkill" "ideapad-laptop". Also, the "acer-wmi" module seems to be loading. I'm not sure this is doing any harm, but the brightness and volume seem to work without it.